# Can't get element nested within Boostrap popover in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to alert when I click on an anchor tag with id `small-text`.

The element is inside a Bootstrap popover. However, when I remove it and put it anywhere outside the popover, the alert starts workings whenever I click on the link.

I have no idea what's happening.

**DEMO** https://jsfiddle.net/08sa99uk/4/

HTML

```
<div class="article-links">
  <span class="font">
    <a href="#"
       data-container="body"
       data-toggle="popover"
       data-html="true">
      <i class="fa fa-font fa-2x"></i>
    </a>
    <span class="font-size" style="display: none">
      <a href="#nogo" id="small-text">S</a>
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
// This is the function that allows me to use an external div for the popover content
$('.font a').on('click', function(e) {e.preventDefault(); return true; }).popover({
  html: true,
  placement: 'bottom',
  content: function() {
    return $('.font-size').html();
    }
});

$('a#small-text').on('click', function() {
  alert('clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the element in question does not exist when the DOM is rendered. If you inspect the rendered popup (typically, <kbd>F12</kbd> in the browser or right click and *Inspect Element*), that *Bootstrap* is creating, it's copying your template and appending it to the DOM inside the popup wrapper:

```
<div class="popover fade bottom in" role="tooltip" id="popover192086" style="top: 27px; left: 0px; display: block;">
    <div class="arrow" style="left: 31.7073%;"></div>
    <h3 class="popover-title" style="display: none;"></h3>
    <div class="popover-content">
        <a href="#nogo" id="small-text" data-original-title="" title="">S</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Since this occurs, you need to delegate the second click event:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a#small-text', function() {
    alert('clicked');
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/08sa99uk/5/)**

**Note:** It should be noted that delegating at the `document` level is inefficient. You'll want to replace `document` in the code above with the closest parent code that exists in the DOM prior to initialization.

**EDIT:**

Regarding the latest comment below about the delegation not working with `span.font`, here is the fully rendered DOM layout that *Bootstrap* creates:

```
<body>
    <!-- Your original code -->
    <div class="article-links">
        <span class="font">
            <a href="#" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-html="true" data-original-title="" title="" aria-describedby="popover186211">
                <i class="fa fa-font fa-2x"></i>
            </a>
            <span class="font-size" style="display: none">
                <a href="#nogo" id="small-text" data-original-title="" title="">S</a>
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap added code -->
    <div class="popover fade bottom in" role="tooltip" id="popover186211" style="top: 27px; left: 0px; display: block;">
        <div class="arrow" style="left: 31.7073%;"></div>
        <h3 class="popover-title" style="display: none;"></h3>
        <div class="popover-content">
            <a href="#nogo" id="small-text" data-original-title="" title="">S</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Notice that in the *Bootstrap* rendered code, there is not a `span.font`. UI libraries tend to extract user created templates and then add additional code to make them perform in the desired way. In this case, you'd have to add the delegation code to the next outer element, possibly `body`. For your use case, it's probably fine to use `document` this once. I would not make a habit of it though.

Comment: you beat me to it! aghhh

Comment: It works with `document` but I can't get it to work with the closest parent element which is `span.font`

Comment: @Halnex Awesome!  Good luck and happy coding :)